# Is the following sentence good in formal writing?

Tags: politeness, writing

I want to send an email to my professor and thank him. I asked him to change my presentation day since I have an exam on that day and he accepted my request.

Is the following sentence good :

"Thank you very much for your understanding."

Comment: Although this sentence is potentially fine, we can't tell if it's appropriate without further context.

Comment: I asked him to change my presentation day since I have an exam on that day and he accepted my request.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the sentence is 'good'. However, you could make it great by dropping the 'your'.

> Thank you very much for understanding.